# Method to speed up reading the contents of a file

Tags: php, file, loops

In a script I'm having I'm pulling a csv from a remote server using ftp. I save this file locally and then open the file. I loop through all the contents of the file matching a certain value against it. If it matches, the script can continue.

Enough talking. Lets show some code...

```
$filename = 'ftp://.....';
$localCsv = '/tmp/'.date('Ymd').'.csv';
if (!file_exists($localCsv)) {
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    file_put_contents($localCsv, $content);
}
```

Now that we have the file created. We can continue to loop.

```
$handle = fopen($localCsv, "r");
while(!feof($handle)) {
  $rows[] = fgets($handle);
}
fclose($handle);

$results = array();
foreach ($rows as $rid => $row) {
    $columns = explode("\t", $row);
    $results[$columns[2]] = $columns;
}

if (array_key_exists($searchValue, $results)) {
    ... Continue script ...
}
```

There is just one tiny little problem with this method. It's so slow it's almost going backwards.

Comment: Which bit is slow..?  Getting the file, or looping through it?  What is the filesize of the .csv file?  Have you considered gettigng the file via cURL?

Comment: is it the reading/writing in the first, or the iterating in the second step that takes time?

Comment: It's not the reading/writing that's slow as this is done only once a day.

Comment: Would it be quicker to use RegEx to find a match and then continue?

Comment: so the iterating is slow? you could read the rows and do your processing in the same loop. Instead of two as you have, and also look for the search-key in the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres all baked together, maybe thats faster?

```
$handle = fopen($localCsv, "r");
$results = array();
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $columns = explode("\t", fgets($handle));
    $results[$columns[2]] = $columns;
    if ($columns[2] == $searchValue) {
        //SEARCH HIT
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

If thats not working you could try the [csv-specific methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) that are in PHP